# Search with mongo does not work perfectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following search method:

```
if (cond == 'AMB') {

        amb.find({
          $or: [
              {PROCEDIMENTO: new RegExp(query , "i")},
              {CODIGO: new RegExp(query , "i")}
          ]
        }
      )
     .exec(function(err, result) {
       if (err) {
         res.status(500).json(err);
       } else {
         res.json(result);
       }
     })

    } else if (cond == 'TUSS') {
        tuss.find({
            $or: [
                {PROCEDIMENTO: new RegExp(query , "i")},
                {CODIGO: new RegExp(query , "i")}
            ]
          }
        )
       .exec(function(err, result) {
         if (err) {
           res.status(500).json(err);
         } else {
           res.json(result);
         }
       })

    }
```

Model TUSS:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var tuss = new Schema({
    CODIGO: String,
    PROCEDIMENTO: String,
  CH: String
}, {collection: 'tuss'});

tuss.index({'CODIGO': 'text', 'PROCEDIMENTO': 'text'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('tuss', tuss);
```

Model AMB:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var amb = new Schema({
    CODIGO: String,
    PROCEDIMENTO: String,
  CH: String
}, {collection: 'amb'});

amb.index({'CODIGO': 'text', 'PROCEDIMENTO': 'text'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('amb', amb);
```

When the condition is AMB I have query results, but when it is TUSS the return is empty.

Example of object in mongo:

TUSS:

```
 {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a0480cf6033716ecefbdc6f"
    },
    "CODIGO": 20104219,
    "PROCEDIMENTO ": "SESSÃO DE PSICOTERAPIA INDIVIDUAL",
    "CH": 100
 }
```

AMB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a047b9e6033716ecefb42db"
    },
    "CODIGO": "00040029",
    "PROCEDIMENTO": "U.T.I. PEDIAT.NEONATAL (12HS.P/PACIENTE)",
    "CH": 300
}
```

If I put in my query AMB 00040029 or U.T.I works. If I put in my query TUSS 20104219 or SESSÃO or even SESSÃO DE PSICOTERAPIA INDIVIDUAL does not work.

I can not understand since the methods and models are the same. My mongo is staying at mLAB.

Comment: The `CODIGO` field in your TUSS example document is a number, not a string.  Also, if you are querying with regular expressions, instead of doing a mongo text search, then your text indexes will not be used.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/.  If you want to do RegEx querying, you can simply index the field itself normally. 
 Lastly, I don't have time to test it, but you may be running into problems with diacritic sensitivity.

Comment: In addition to what you mentioned, the "PROCEDIMENTO " of the TUSS table had a space after the letter O.

It took me a few hours to find out hehe

After fixing this I converted the code to String and now it works fine.

Thanks